# Insert into two tables at once MS access

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables that have "one to many" connection. I want to import data from excel workbook into these tables.

What's the best way to do it?

For now, I'm importing data separately into each table.

I've searched on the internet but couldn't find the answer, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Comment: You can't do it at once. You always must insert the records into the table on the 1-side of the relation first and then into the n-side because the n-side table has a foreign key pointing to the 1-side.

Comment: Write an after-update data-macro for the first table to insert automatically records in the second table.

Comment: How are you currently accomplishing this import - manually with External Data wizard? Write code to perform the two steps and will appear as one.